# Why is skimage.io.ImageCollection returning every other image in a folder as an empty tuple?

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook, scikit-image

I have followed the advanced ski-image panoramic image tutorial [(1)](https://github.com/scikit-image/skimage-demos/blob/master/pano/pano-advanced.ipynb) and gotten it to work properly. However, trying to use UAV images (Adobe Buttes Flight 1 Raw) downloaded from [(2)](https://dronemapper.com/sample_data), results in an interesting problem when using the skimage ImageCollection. Printing the problem images gives me some sort of wrapper:

"PIL.MpoImagePlugin.MpoImageFile image mode=RGB size=4000x3000 at 0x1EB09B86D30"

If I use io.imread to read a problem image it appears to work, printing a shape of "(2,)". However, attempting to print the individually read image gives a type error:

"unorderable types: int() >= MpoImageFile()"

followed by a system error:

"method-wrapper '**le**' of MpoImageFile object at 0x000001EB09F20CC0 returned a result with an error set"

I'm really at a loss here. I'm relatively new to python and don't understand why the programs not working. The images are a bit large (5.65 mb) but my main program handles (slowly) the 'good' images.

I've tried the following solutions to no avail:
1) uninstalling pillow, installing both libjpeg & libz (the names seem to have changed) then reinstalling pillow github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2000.
2) I'm not using a GPU, parallel processing, or tensorflow github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2000,
3) I've also made sure my Anaconda version is fully updated

This is the minimalist example I made to demonstrate the issue. It should run in any jupyter notebook.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage import io


imgs = io.ImageCollection('test\*')

"""
print(imgs[0])   # Looks okay, numpy array
print(imgs[1])   # wrapper
print(imgs[2])   # Looks okay, numpy array
"""

for i in range(6):
    print(np.shape(imgs[i]))


individual = io.imread('test\DJI_0002.jpg')
print(np.shape(individual))

#print(individual)
```

After some more testing this issue goes away when the images are resized at 50%. Is there a limit to the image size scimage can read? This is still not an acceptable solution, I would greatly prefer not having to resize all images that get pieced together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [image read through skimage.io.imread have suspicious shape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41196754/image-read-through-skimage-io-imread-have-suspicious-shape)