# image read through skimage.io.imread have suspicious shape

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am trying to read an RGB image using the skimage.io.imread. But after reading the image, I found that the image shape is wrong, `print(img.shape)` shows that
the image shape is `(2,)`. The complete code to show the problem is:

```
from skimage import io
img = io.imread(path/to/the/image)
print(img.shape)
```

I also tried to read the image using opencv's python package, the returned shape is correct (height*width*3).

The skimage version used is **0.12.3**, can someone explain is there anything wrong with my way using the package or is this really a bug?

Click the link for <del>the test image</del>

### Edit1

The test image is altered when it is uploaded, the unaltered version is [here](https://github.com/csucat/markdown_photos/blob/master/156.jpg). I have also opened [an issue](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2406) on the skimage github repo, and it turns out that the test image is
a two-frame image, but the second frame is empty. You can consider this image
a "corrupted" image.

In order to read the right image, you can use this workaround, `img = io.imread(/path/to/the/image, img_num=0)`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. I have downloaded the image, then I run your code (using the same version of skimage) and obtained: `(978L, 2000L, 3L)`.

Comment: @Tonechas, the test image is altered when it is uploaded. I have updated the link of the test image. The correct md5sum is 6bc94ff2d3a2ea82b514051ec182ee97. This image should reproduce the issue.

Comment: I was having issue with skimage when trying to upload the image to cloud may be because of compression and decompression. used the ,img_num=0 and the problem got fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can fix this issue by enforcing `skimage.io.imread()` to use **matplotlib**:

```
In [131]: from skimage import io

In [132]: img = io.imread('156.jpg', plugin='matplotlib')

In [133]: img.shape
Out[133]: (978L, 2000L, 3L)
```

Your image is likely to be a multi object JPG. If you try to read it using **PIL** (which is the default plugin) you get a NumPy array which consists of two objects. The first object is the image itself and the second one might be a thumbnail, but PIL does not handle it properly:

```
In [157]: img = io.imread('156.jpg', plugin='pil')

In [158]: img.dtype
Out[158]: dtype('O')

In [159]: img.shape
Out[159]: (2L,)

In [160]: img[0].shape
Out[160]: (978L, 2000L, 3L)

In [161]: img[1]
Out[161]: array(<PIL.MpoImagePlugin.MpoImageFile image mode=RGB size=2000x978 at 0x111DBCF8>, dtype=object)
```

Take a look at [this thread](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2154) to find out more on this problem.

Comment: yes, that image can be considered "corrupted" because it has two layers. But I think explicitly tell imread which plugin to use is cumbersome since most images are "good" ones. And this issue hasn't been fixed yet.

Answer (score 1):

Check the type of image being uploaded by you.

If you upload a color image you will get the size of the image along with the number of channels `(1920, 2560, 3)`.

As long as the uploaded image is a color image you will receive 3.

Or else if the image is a gray-scale or binary you will get the size of the image `(1920, 2560)`

Comment: The original uploaded image is altered in the uploading process. I have update the link of the test image. It should reproduce the issue.